# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [ExpressionEngine® Answers](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [PHP errors after upgrading to Playa 4.4.4](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11919/php-errors-after-upgrading-to-playa-4-4-4)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Wygwam 3.0.2 PHP Error in EE 2.5.5](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/wygwam-3-0-2-php-error-in-ee-2-5-5)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Has color button gone on the latest Wygwam 3.0.2?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12460/has-color-button-gone-on-the-latest-wygwam-3-0-2)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Assets plugin not working at all](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12064/assets-plugin-not-working-at-all)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Calling extension or module method from plugin](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11974/calling-extension-or-module-method-from-plugin)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Add-ons are linking incorrectly in control panel](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12558/add-ons-are-linking-incorrectly-in-control-panel)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Using Postmaster to Auto Send total amount sold of an item](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/using-postmaster-to-auto-send-total-amount-sold-of-an-item)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Search both channel fields and related entries fields](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12478/search-both-channel-fields-and-related-entries-fields)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Freeform Pro: Notifying Any Email Except Domain Email](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12624/freeform-pro-notifying-any-email-except-domain-email)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [safecracker + ajax = readyState: 4 on home page](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12441/safecracker-ajax-readystate-4-on-home-page)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

Comment: Are these good results? Can we get feedback on our beta?

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl You guys are doing _very_ well, we've taken a very close look at the last two reviews. Keep doing what you're doing and it won't be long.